# Analytics doesn't reliably exclude (major) search engines from 'Referring Sites'

Tags: bug, site-analytics

On the 'traffic sources' tab, results from a couple of search engines are overwhelming the 'Referring Sites' graph:

[image]

Specifically, the top 2 referring sites are 'bing.com' and 'duckduckgo.com', which are both search engines.  Also included are 'global.bing.com' and 'r.duckduckgo.com'.

I don't know what the exact criteria is for declaring one thing a "search engine" and another a "referring site", but the purpose seems to be to exclude sites whose primary purpose is general-search from being presented as a referring site?

If so, it seems like all '*.bing.com' and '*.duckduckgo.com' hits should be rolled into the 'Search Engines' list and excluded from 'Referring Sites'?  The 'Top Ten Referring Sites' chart would certainly be a lot more useful if bing and duckduckgo weren't on there.

**Edit** - Here's how it should look:

[image]

Poor Yahoo, they're losing to bing *and* duckduckgo.

Comment: The [Site Analytics privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) mentions "There are a few oddities in the data: DuckDuckGo shows up as a referring site and not a search engine."

Comment: The data comes from Google Analytics and the breakdown is on that end.

Comment: @Oded - I thought that might be the case.  However, the raw data is being passed to the page, and then on to the charts API.  So if it has known issues, there's an opportunity to correct it before it gets there.  For instance, like so:  http://jsfiddle.net/vs47dh84/1/

Comment: _"Since this is a restricted privilege, we'd prefer you not share the raw data."_ ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics))

Comment: @Cerbrus - "_However, we do hope you will share your analysis of the data with other users on meta._"  My analysis of the data is it needs fixing (and also, damn, Google makes everything else completely irrelevant).  Besides, there's nothing here (or on jsFiddle) that [people haven't seen before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260849/proposed-micro-privilege-site-analytics).

Comment: I'm just saying, blatantly posting a screenshot appears to be in conflict with that request.

Comment: And perhaps it is.  Though other verbiage on that page also appears to conflict with the request.  And I can't personally see anything wrong with sharing the info here (especially when it effectively illustrates the issue), which is the main thing.  So not that concerned, to be honest.  An SE employee has obviously been here, and I assume would have taken action if it was an actual problem.